# vector of integers

Tags: c++, vector, int

I'd like to convert a vector to an integer. I can output the vector using

```
vector <int> iV;

iV.push_back(3);
iV.push_back(8);
iV.push_back(6);

copy(iV.begin(),iV.end(),ostream_iterator<int>(cout,""))
```

But how can I get this to an int?

EDIT: Using stringstream works fine for what I'm doing.
I did want to see exactly what it looked like via cout.
I didn't want exact int by int I meant one single int so for my example it would be an int equaling 386.
Thanks everyone for there help really appreciate it.

Comment: What would you expect the `int` to contain in this case?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams the same thing he is seeing via cout?

Comment: @Acebond: You mean you want to extract the values int by int ? is that it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write it out to stringstream and then read from it like so:

```
std::stringstream strStream;
copy(iV.begin(),iV.end(),ostream_iterator<int>(strStream,""));
int myInt;
strStream >> myInt;
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Works beautifully and epic response time.

Comment: This is not terribly efficent. Why go via a string?

Comment: @Hasan Khan: Common sense dictates that when it's just as easy (or easier) to do something efficiently you should. At the very least a caveat would be nice.

Comment: @Hasan Khan: I didn’t mean to offend you when I commented that your code was inefficient. On the topic of readability and maintainability something that involves iteration, multiplication by 10 and addition beats ostringstreams any day.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if that's what you mean, but you could do:

```
int * ip = &iv[0];
```

and then access `ip[0]`, `ip[1]`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
int x;
for(vector<int>::const_iterator i = iV.begin(); i != iV.end(); i++)
    x = *i;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
int total = 0;
for(vector<int>::const_iterator i = iV.begin(); i != iV.end(); ++i)
    total = total*10 + *i;
```

Comment: This probably only works as expected for single-digit ints, of course.

Comment: @Peter: Yeah. I unconsciously assumed the vector contained digits.

Comment: What you need to multiply by might be computed with something like: `n > 0 ? std::pow(10, int(std::log10(n) + 1)) : 10` (http://ideone.com/9efpn)

Comment: Thanks Steve, this would seem more efficient.